# How do I duplicate this code for multiple attributes without it displaying "NaN"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code worked for Strength until I duplicated it to work for additional code and it disabled the button. I was wondering how to make it convert it to other areas i.e. Agility. I'm using strength as a fill in for the values as a fill in but I don't know how to work it from there.

```
 <script>

 var strength = 0;

  document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML = strength;

  function updateButtonDisabled() {

  // If strength less than equal zero disable the button
  if(strength <= 0) {
  document.getElementById("subButton").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  else {
  document.getElementById("subButton").removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
  }

  function subStrength(){
  strength = strength - 1;
  document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML = strength;

  updateButtonDisabled();
  }

  function addStrength(){
  strength = strength + 1;
  document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML = strength;

  updateButtonDisabled();
  }

  <th scope="col">
  <button class="button" type="button" onclick="subStrength();" 
  value="subtract">-</button>
  <th><span id="strength"></span></th>

  <th scope="col">
  <button class="button" type="button" onclick="addStrength()" value="add">+ 
  </button>
  </th>

  </th>
```

Comment: You don't duplicate the code in the first place; what you do is write reusable code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3u2kfLn5/

Comment: So your code works in JSfiddle, but as soon as I move it into my code, the buttons won't work

Comment: The JS code has to run after the buttons already exist; in case you have the `<script>` in the document's `<head>`, move it to the end of `<body>` instead, right before `</body>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't exactly reusable code, and there are some missing components, such as `id` attributes. The best way you're going to be able to reuse this code is by creating a function that generates the buttons for you, that way the scope of the add/sub functions is correct. Here's a pure JavaScript solution I created for you.

Also, it appears you're creating a game, possibly an RPG, in that case, I'd highly suggest you use a framework that designed around reusable components, such as React. And if you're not keen on that, at least jQuery to make element creation more enjoyable.

```js
var stats = {
  strength: 0,
  agility: 1,
  speed: 2
}

function disableButton (button, value) {
  if (value <= 0) {
    button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}

function createButton(stat) {
  const wrapperEl = document.createElement('section');
  const labelEl = document.createElement('span');
  const leftEl = document.createElement('button');
  const valueEl = document.createElement('span');
  const rightEl = document.createElement('button');
  
  labelEl.innerText = ` ${stat}`;
  valueEl.innerText = stats[stat];
  leftEl.innerHTML = '-';
  rightEl.innerHTML = '+';
  leftEl.onclick = function () {
    stats[stat]--;
    valueEl.innerText = stats[stat];
    disableButton(this, stats[stat]);
  }
  rightEl.onclick = function () {
    stats[stat]++;
    valueEl.innerText = stats[stat];
    disableButton(leftEl, stats[stat]);
  }
  
  if (stats[stat] <= 0) {
    leftEl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  
  wrapperEl.appendChild(leftEl);
  wrapperEl.appendChild(valueEl);
  wrapperEl.appendChild(rightEl);
  wrapperEl.appendChild(labelEl);
  
  return wrapperEl;
}

// Wrapped in DOMContentLoaded event listener
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  Object.keys(stats).forEach(function(stat) {
    document.getElementById('stats').appendChild(createButton(stat))
  });
});
```

```html
<section id="stats"></section>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, only problem is no buttons show. I've replaced the JS and that didn't work, I then removed the button HTML code and that just removed the buttons all together. Anything you could think of?

Comment: This solution generates all the HTML in JavaScript and puts it inside an element with the `id` of `stats`. If you're looking to just copy/paste this JS into your page, you'll need to remove all your button HTML and just put `<section id="stats"></section>` where it used to be.

Comment: I tried that and it just shows my background, I'll give it another shot.

Comment: So nothing shows, I've tried taking out just the table and button code, and the whole code, but nothing seems to be displaying.

Comment: Can you put your code on jsFiddle.net so I can see the full context?

Comment: Just had to put the JS into the <section id="stats"></section>

Comment: That's not a good solution. The issue you're encountering is that you've included my JS BEFORE the `<section id="stats"><section>`. You can either put the JS at the bottom of the page, or wrap it in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});`

Comment: Yeah no, I put it after the <section id="stats"><section> . It works perfectly fine, thank you. Only challenge left is to relocate the buttons to the centre of the right div and have the css work on the buttons and look the way I want them to.

Comment: You can add a class before `appendChild` by doing this. `wrapperEl.classList.add('mystyle')`. Then you can target the buttons and value field with CSS selectors.

Comment: Also, be sure to accept the answer if this solved your problem

Comment: So that kinda worked, it highlights the full length of it, so the row from beginning to end of the div. Which is kinda nice, but I'm more so after getting the individual buttons to change. Thanks.

Comment: You can either add a class to the button, or access it through css selectors like .myStyle button {background-color: red}

Comment: I'm quite happy with it now actually. Thanks for all your help!